# C# - Microsoft Word Automation - Create a new page using the same template

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a specific template I have use for every page. It is essentially two columns of tables with 1 column and 1 row. Why the whole thing is not one table I do not know, but I am stuck with it. It looks like the following. Again each cell is actually its own table. So there is 40 tables on the page. These will be used as labels in a binder. Note that a table on the left is duplicated on the right. This is because they fold over and will be used as one.

[image]

What I need is to duplicate this to a new page and start over every time a page fills up and the count exceeds 20.

My code is as follows:

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
        var doc = app.Documents.Add(@"C:\.....LabelTemplate.dotx");
        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
        object pageBreak = Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak;
        Word.Selection selection = app.Selection;

        string path = Path.Combine(destination, "labels.docx");
        int page = 1;
        foreach (var batch in batches)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i <= batch.Count(); i++)
            {

                Word.Table table = doc.Tables[i];

                table.Range.Font.Size = 7;
                table.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
                table.Range.Font.Bold = 1;

                int x = i - 1;
                string text = batch[x].WellName + "\v" + batch[x].Field + "\v" + batch[x].Reservior;
                //int cellNum = i + 1;
                table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = text;

                Word.Table table2 = doc.Tables[i + 20];

                table2.Range.Font.Size = 7;
                table2.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
                table2.Range.Font.Bold = 1;

                table2.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = text;

                if (i % 20 == 0)
                {
                    selection.EndKey(Word.WdUnits.wdStory, Word.WdMovementType.wdMove);
                    selection.InsertBreak(ref pageBreak);

                }

            }
            page++;

        }

        doc.SaveAs(path);
        doc.Close();
        app.Quit();
```

Comment: Select the entirety and save it as a **Building Block" entry in the template. (Do this as a user). Then you can insert the Building Block entry as required.

Comment: have added the building block. Would you have an example of how to access this via code?

Answer (score 1):

Building Blocks provide a convenient way to store and re-use "boiler-plate"  in Word documents. The content can be "plain text" or include formatting and all things supported by Word. This is often easier and faster than trying to recreate content using code or importing content from an outside file.

Building Blocks are stored in templates (dotx or dotm). A template can be attached to a document (usually when a document is created from that template) or it can be "global", such as Normal.dotm.

In this case, the Building Block is stored in the attached template and will be available to any document created from that template (but not for other documents).

Building Blocks can be organized into "Types" and "Categories", meaning there can be multiple Building Blocks in a template "container" with the same name. If that's the case, it's necessary to specify the Building Block type, category and name when addressing it. If the name is unique in the template, then only the name is required.

The following code snippet shows both possibilities. The two Building Blocks are inserted one after the other at the end of the Document object.

A Building Block is inserted using the `Insert` method.

```
Word.Range rng = doc.Content;
rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
Word.Template objTmpl = (Word.Template) doc.get_AttachedTemplate(); // NormalTemplate
Word.BuildingBlock objBB = objTmpl.BuildingBlockEntries.Item("TestCCwithActiveX");
objBB.Insert(rng, true);
rng = doc.Content;
rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
Word.BuildingBlock objBB2 = objTmpl.BuildingBlockTypes.Item(Word.WdBuildingBlockTypes.wdTypeAutoText).Categories.Item("Test").BuildingBlocks.Item("test heading");
objBB2.Insert(rng, true);
```